# HERE SDK Geocode Request

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to using GeocodeRequest to get the coordinate by giving place name like this http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#geocoding

and I had checked and follow the documentation https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/geocoding.html, but I get error with the listener

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2rk1.png

Does anyone have experience of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the import statement of the Location class,

I guess you are importing android.location.Location, you should import com.here.android.mpa.search.Location